# Why do sys.columns and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS display different number of columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying two methods to display the columns with a particular name:

1. **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS**

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   WHERE COLUMN_NAME='SUPPLIER_NAME';
   ```
2. **SYS.COLUMNS**

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM SYS.COLUMNS
   WHERE NAME='SUPPLIER_NAME'
   ```

Why do the queries display different output?

[image: SSMS screen grab]

Comment: I have only 4 Column's in my Database.But Using  sys.columns it ill display 5 Record i don't no Why?

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is just a view over `sys.columns` that `INNER JOIN`s to `sys.objects` and restricts to object types of Table or View. My guess is that one of your records in `sys.columns` is eliminated in this restriction.

Comment: They both are different a bit. Please read http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/183/informationschemacolumns/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx I would say you should have read documentation before posting

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference between `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and `sys.columns` is the object types they cover. `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is restricted to tables and views.  You can take a look at the code behind it by doing this:

```
EXEC sp_helptext [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS]
```

If you look at the bottom in the where clause you will see

```
o.type IN ('U', 'V')
```

This is where it is restricted to the tables and views only.

If you then go look at the definition of sys.columns you will see that it includes columns for a number of other objects:

- Table-valued assembly functions (FT)
- Inline table-valued SQL functions (IF)
- Internal tables (IT)
- System tables (S)
- Table-valued SQL functions (TF)

Run this and you will be able to see what the extra object is and what type it is.

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
    OBJECTPROPERTYEX(object_id, 'BASETYPE'), *
FROM sys.columns
```